# Can I use Bazel Build for Fortify SCA scan of C++ app?

Tags: c++, bazel, fortify, bazel-cpp

I am trying to scan a c++ project. I have multiple c++ files which I translated with `sourceanalyzer -b <buildID> file.cpp files.h` which seemed to be done successfully but no output.

Tried the following:

1. When I try to `-b <buildID> -show-build-warnings` I am getting the following error:

   ```
   [error]: Unable to load build session with ID "<buildID>". See log file for more details.
   ```
2. When I try to print out results with `sourceanalyzer –b <buildID> -scan -f results.fpr` I an getting another error

   ```
   [error]: No rules files found
   ```
3. And also when I try to do a generic build with touchless build: `/sourceanalyzer –b <buildID> touchless bazel build /src/<buildID>:<buildID>` (this last part with bazel build is how we always build the project) this also fails and gets an error

   ```
   [error]: touchless build integration requires the -b option.
   ```

   Although I already have `-b <buildID>` option.
4. Additionally I also tried touchless build with: 
   `sourceanalyzer –b build1 touchless g++ src/file.cpp -I include/path` 
   and it didn't work it returned an error

   ```
   [error]: touchless build integration requires the -b option.
   ```

If someone knows a workaround or what I did wrong please let me know